# How to import list from 'list form txt file'?

Tags: python-3.6

I'm making some python3 programs working with very huge list(about 5000 items). I think 'import list from txt files' will be convenient for my programs. But python imports like string, not list.

I make txt files like....

```
["a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "d"....]
```

and using f.read, f.readlines, f.readline functions to read txt files.

```
f=open('list.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')

exception_list=f.read()
list(exception_list)
print(exception_list[0])
```

I expect the output `a`

but the actual output is `[`.

But, when I print whole variable which read from txt files,

```
print(exception_list)
```

than that print like that

```
["a","1","b",....]
```

How can I import list from txt files?

Comment: expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ast`, With ast.literal_eval, you can safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

```
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(exception_list)
>>> x
["a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3", "d"....]
```